# movie atom problem in mp4 conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

In our project, we convert any given video file into mp4 file which works fine when we publish it via our site.

But when we publish the stream link in our itunes-rss and try to download and play the files in Itunes or quicktime, we get an error on the movie-atom in some of the movies and those don't play as they're downloaded to local machine.

After some research, we got that the problem is in the framerate value, to be more specific, the problem is related with 32bit - 64bit value differences. And the conversion should be done with the following formula: 
newFrameRate = (int(oldFrameRate)+1)*(1000/1001) 
- as we found so far.

We tried to learn the framerate value through ffmpeg and movieinfo, but the results were always different and not accurate.

What's your suggestion to solve this issue? 
Tolga

Comment: Please try FFmpeg SVN version first, if it doesn't work; please report this to FFmpeg bugzilla with a proper sample & how-to reproduce info: http://roundup.ffmpeg.org/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one useful way to solve this problem and wanted to report.

I installed MP4Box, and used
mp4box -frag 1000

which solves all the moov-atom related problems.

I tried other values for fragmantation but in larger values, second half of the movie loose its movie track and turns into white.

FYI, 
Tolga